# Python: split a string by the position of a character

Tags: python, string, split, find

How can I split a string by the position of a word?

My data looks like this:

```
test = 'annamarypeterson, Guest Relations Manager, responded to this reviewResponded 1 week agoDear LoreLoreLore,Greetings from Amsterdam!We have received your wonderful comments and wanted to thank you for sharing your positive experience with us. We are so thankful that you have selected the Andaz Amsterdam for your special all-girls weekend getaway. Please come and see us again in the near future and let our team pamper you and your girlfriends!!Thanks again!Anna MaryAndaz Amsterdam -Guest RelationsReport response as inappropriateThank you. We appreciate your input.This response is the subjective opinion of the management representative'
```

I need this output:

```
responder = 'annamarypeterson, Guest relations Manager'
date = 'Responded 1 week ago'
response = 'Dear ....' #without 'This response is the subjective opinion of the management representative'
```

I know that the `find.()` function gives the position of a word, and I want to use this position to tell Python where to split it. For example:

```
splitat = test.find('ago')+3
```

What function can I use to split with an integer? The `split()` function does not work with an int.

Comment: Treat the string as an array - use the str[:splitat] notation

Comment: Strings are list of charachters and support slicing

Comment: Python strings are basically immutable list, you can just use slice i think, test[splitat:splitat+3] for exemple.

Comment: If you can affect the way the original data looks, go for it. The format you have to work with does not favor you at all. If you can**not**, pick one of the solutions posted below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this with strings (and lists) using slicing:

```
string = "hello world!"
splitat = 4
left, right = string[:splitat], string[splitat:]
```

will result in:

```
>>> left
hell
>>> right
o world!
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the simplest solution is to use string slicing:

```
test = 'annamarypeterson, Guest Relations Manager, responded to this reviewResponded 1 week agoDear LoreLoreLore,Greetings from Amsterdam!We have received your wonderful comments and wanted to thank you for sharing your positive experience with us. We are so thankful that you have selected the Andaz Amsterdam for your special all-girls weekend getaway. Please come and see us again in the near future and let our team pamper you and your girlfriends!!Thanks again!Anna MaryAndaz Amsterdam -Guest RelationsReport response as inappropriateThank you. We appreciate your input.This response is the subjective opinion of the management representative'
pos = test.find('ago') + 3
print(test[:pos], test[pos:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a built in function for you.

```
import re    
test = 'annamarypeterson, Guest Relations Manager, responded to this reviewResponded 1 week agoDear LoreLoreLore,Greetings from Amsterdam!We have received your wonderful comments and wanted to thank you for sharing your positive experience with us. We are so thankful that you have selected the Andaz Amsterdam for your special all-girls weekend getaway. Please come and see us again in the near future and let our team pamper you and your girlfriends!!Thanks again!Anna MaryAndaz Amsterdam -Guest RelationsReport response as inappropriateThank you. We appreciate your input.This response is the subjective opinion of the management representative'

m = re.search('ago', test)
response = test[m.end():]
```

This is the object produced by regex: <re.Match object; span=(41, 44), match='ago'>

You can use m.start() to get the position of the first character and m.end() to get the last character.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html