# How to slice in django template by a string

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I just want to slice a string on django in two parts, passing a caracter like "|"

Example: 2007-007134|10003L

Part 1: 2007-007134

Part 2: 10003L

I tried somethings but without success

Someone can help me?

Comment: do you mean like this ? if you have it like:   example="2007-007134|10003L" then Part_1= example[:10] and part_2=example[12:]

Comment: The code length is not fixed, I have a code like NE | 02023, in this case, it cannot slice correctly.

Comment: how about a split point , like a dash or a point etc, then slice on it,  like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766530/python-split-a-string-by-the-position-of-a-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved according Maciej Rogosz recommended:
Custom Template Tag

First: I created the folder templatetags inside of my app, after that create a empty **ini**.py and finally created my custom_tag.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='split1')
def split1(value, key):
  return value.split(key)[1]

@register.filter(name='split2')
def split2(value, key):
  return value.split(key)[0]
```

In my tamplate I have to load the template tags

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

And call my custom_tags: split1, split2

```
{{ instance.mat_code|split1:"|" }}
{{ instance.mat_code|split2:"|" }}
```

That is it, python + django = Magic

Tks to everyone for your help

Ref1: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Ref2: https://www.codementor.io/@hiteshgarg14/creating-custom-template-tags-in-django-application-58wvmqm5f

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom template tag. They are basically python code which you can execute from inside the html templates (when using defult Django templating engine).

You can read more about them here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/
https://www.codementor.io/@hiteshgarg14/creating-custom-template-tags-in-django-application-58wvmqm5f